# PHP header xls using .xlsx

Tags: php, excel, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I Use this code for exporting excel

```
<?php
 header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 ?>
```

But i can't change $title.xls to .xlsx format

Please give me solution

Comment: Is the file an actual excel file? Setting HTTP headers with PHP doesn't actually convert anything.

Answer (score 0):

change content type. Try the following code to download files with $title formate

```
        $file = $title.".xlsx";
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i use this code, and not work, you can see this :



[link](https://imageshack.com/i/pm4vmgv2j)

Answer (score 0):

For BIFF .xls files

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```